# How can I use the default Folder View in a Shell Namespace Extension?

Tags: winapi, com, atl, explorer, windows-shell

I've been researching how to implement a Namespace Extension.

The NSE should show files and folders (they are **physical files and folders**, but **located elsewhere on the disk**).

Also, the NSE must **behave as closely as possible to the normal Explorer view**, e.g. it must have:

- Context menus that would normally appear in a normal Explorer view that are applicable to the file/folder(s) chosen
- Drag and drop (both of files/folders and other things like Document Scraps)
- 'Right Drag and Drop' (e.g. 7Zips 'Extract here...')
- Clipboard Copy/Cut/Paste
- Share With entries
- Any registered Shell Icon Overlay Handlers must work (e.g. Tortoise SVN/GIT)
- Column sizing/re-ordering
- View customisation, including ordering and grouping

So, basically anything the Explorer view can do so must we.

Looking at all the things that Explorer can do *(that I used to take for granted)*, I felt a bit overwhelmed.

Because I'm both lazy and a realist (I realise it'd be near impossible to replicate all this functionality without issue), my plan is to **reuse the functionality of the Explorer view in my NSE**.

I've looked at various samples of NSEs.  Most of these use virtual data, but as I said, I'm representing physical files and folder elsewhere on the disk.  I've also read about the `SHCreateShellFolderView` method.

Armed with this information, I thought it'd be a relatively simple case of providing a `PIDL` of my root folder and then in my `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject` call `SHCreateShellFolder` method.  Here is that method:

```
STDMETHODIMP CShellFolderImpl::CreateViewObject( 
    HWND hwndOwner, 
    REFIID riid, 
    void** ppvOut )
{
    HRESULT hr=E_NOINTERFACE;

    if ( NULL == ppvOut )
        return E_POINTER;

    *ppvOut = NULL;

    if (riid == IID_IShellView)
    {
        SFV_CREATE SfvCreate = 
        {
            sizeof(SFV_CREATE) 
        };


        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&SfvCreate.pshf))))
        {
            hr = ::SHCreateShellFolderView(
                &SfvCreate, 
                reinterpret_cast<IShellView **>(ppvOut));
        }

        SfvCreate.pshf->Release();
    }
    else if (riid == IID_ITransferSource)
    {

    }

    return hr;
}
```

No such luck with that. `SHCreateShellFolderView` was always returning `E_NOTIMPL`. Turns out that this is because it requires a pointer to something implementing `IShellFolder2` (and `IPersist2` for `GetCurFolder` where I can provide my `PIDL`).  My folder just implemented `IShellFolder` and `IPerist`.

So after changing these to implement the newer interfaces, I got... nothing!  The NSE would be loaded by Explorer, the constructor would be called, but immediately after, the destructor would be called.  If I changed the interfaces back to how they were, it fired up (but still with the same problem).

I've since been looking for a **sample that implements `IShellFolder2`**, but again, the documentation is as bad as it is for the rest of these APIs.

**How can I use `SHCreateShellFolderView` so that I don't have to reimplement everything Explorer already does?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are able to use and embed a Windows Explorer window for your namespace extension, the problem is that you are no longer in control of what it does. For example, if the user double-clicks on a folder, the actual filesystem folder will be browsed, not your namespace extension node which represents the filesystem folder.

Your only option is to do your own implementation. Check out [EZNamespaceExtensionsMFC](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensionsmfc.htm) which makes it very easy to develop namespace extensions. It has a "FileSystemBrowser" sample which you can use as a starting point.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP, the developers of EZNamespaceExtensionsMFC.